# Grails return CSV

Tags: grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am working on Grails 2.4.0 and I would like to return CSV file to the browser.

export plugin doesn't work - I get
Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not transfer artifact org.grails.plugins:export:jar:1.6

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add this in your **plugins** -

```
 compile(":export:1.6") {
        exclude "bcprov-jdk14"
 }
```

*For me is working (grails 2.3.11)